# Is there a way to use fake class (without database table/model) for polymorphic relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism, laravel-relations

I have a `transactions` table that has transaction types that morph to `TopUpTransaction`, `DeductTransaction`, etc. that holds their specific informations (as they have different fields).

Now I have a transaction type `SecurityDeposit` that doesn't need to have a dedicated model as it doesn't need any extra information.

I can make it work with default morph by having a model and an db table that keeps only `id` field, but this is none sense.

Is there way to get around creating an empty model and database table?

```
class Transaction extends Model {

    public function transactionable(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function text() 
    {
        return $this->transactionable->text()
    }

    public function class() 
    {
        return $this->transactionable->class()
    }
}
```

```
class TopUpTransaction extends Model {

    public function text() {
        return "Top Up"
    }

    public function class() {
        return "text-success"
    }
}

class DeductTransaction extends Model {
 // has text() and class() methods 
}
```

However, I don't want to create SecurityDepositTransaction in database as it won't need any additional information

```
class SecurityDepositTransaction { 
    
    public function text() {
        return "Security Deposit"
    }

    public function class() {
        return "text-danger"
    }
}
```

Comment: Make a classic morph class (not an eloquent morph relation) that extend Transation. you will have to set some attributes like $table and such, maybe overload the other relations.
For the relation, you can just return a new instance of SecurityDeposit with the attribute of the intanciated Transaction class

Comment: @N69S What do you mean by morph class? Can you please write it in answer section showing your approach?

Answer (score 0):

classic polymorphic relation between SecurityDeposit and Transaction

```php
class SecurityDeposit extends Transaction
{
    protected $table = 'transactions';
    
    // and use it as if you use Transaction, but it will be a seperate class
    // if for example, this class has a special relation that Transaction doesnt have,
    // you declare it here. same for any speccific method to this class

    public function specialRelation() {
        return $this->hasMany(AnotherClass::class);
    }

    public function getDepositAmounr() {
        return $this->custom_data;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this approach will work for `$user->transaction->transactionable` for both models and non-models. Am I missing something?

Comment: it will not work like an eloquent polymorph. for that you need to use an eloquent polymorph.